# Fade background in/out on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Final item will be `background-image`, this test is on `background-color`.

https://jsfiddle.net/broj3064/17/ when you scroll down, red block fades in, but if you scroll up, it doesn't fade out, it just disappears.

HTML

```
<header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="up"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

CSS

```
header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
nav ul li.up {
}
nav ul li.down {
}
.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

/* animation */
nav ul li.down {
    -webkit-animation: bummer 0.5s;
    animation: bummer 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); 
    transform: scale(0,0);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bummer {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    }
}
@keyframes bummer{
    100% {
        transform: scale(1); 
    }
}
nav ul li.up {
    -webkit-animation: bummer2 0.5s;
    animation: bummer2 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,0); 
    transform: scale(1,0);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bummer2 {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
    }
}
@keyframes bummer2{
    100% {
        transform: scale(0); 
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $("li").addClass("down").removeClass("up");
    }
    else {
        $("li").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the `transform: scale(1,0);` in the up class. Perhaps should be `transform: scale(1,1);`?

Comment: @git-e-up this almost works, but now there's initial fade out on page load for some reason.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's because you're starting with the up class on load. You may need to make your js more specific or pull out the up class in the html and start at 1px: `if (scroll >= 1)`. Not exactly sure how you want it to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  $("li").toggleClass('show',(scroll >= 50)); /* toggleClass add or remove a class in a div if you pass a boolean to it, in this case, when scroll is greater than 50 wich its true adds the show class to the selector, in this case a $('li'), otherwise it remove the class */
});
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition:all 400ms; /* This line create an animated transition if any property is overwritten */
    transform:scale(0);
}

nav ul li.show {
  /*Due to css specificity, adding a second class to an item, it overwrite its value, triggering the transition property to animate between old and new value*/
  transform:scale(1);
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

/* animation */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

if it is, hope it helps